# In an aws proxy integration js lambda, is there a correct or standard way to get html form values from event.body, rather than just using querystring?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Have a trivial aws lambda (.mjs file). Have a trivial API gateway, **using proxy integration**.  Have a trivial web form,

```
<form method="post" action="...">
<input type="text" name="team">
<input type="text" name="score">
<input type="submit" value="send">
```

In your lambda, the "event" captures the entire info block sent along from the gateway

```
export const handler = async (event, context) => {
   ...
```

For example you'll find the queryStringParameters here,

queryStringParameters: { example: 'value' },

the headers are here

```
headers: {
 accept: '*/*',
 ...
```

and so on. The actual meat of the matter arrives tagged as "body"

```
body: 'team=sec+west&score=42',
```

actual example!

[image]

***As far as I know*** (seems totally undocumented) the html form parameters are delivered as a url query string -style string.

As such, I have always simply parsed them like this ...

```
import querystring from 'querystring'
...
  if (event.body) {
    console.log('here is the "body" ...')
    console.log(event.body)
    let parsed = querystring.decode(event.body)
    team = parsed.team
```

Do note that this question is strictly and only about ***using proxy integration*** gateway. (Of course you can ***not*** use proxy integration, and instead map it any way you want.)

Note too that this is about ***using a html form***. If you use (for example) curl with the form  `-d '{ "team":"sec, "score":11 }'` that is a completely different thing and it's delivered (via proxy integration mode api gateway) in a completely different way.

(Also, I'm not talking about multipart data, just a vanilla html form.)

So given that `event.body` is

```
body: 'team=sec+west&score=42',
```

(just as seen in the screen shot) what really is the best way to get at the values?

- it seems unusual one has to include a library (say querystring) for such a ubiquitous task. aws's take on node/lambdas has lots of "special" stuff, is there some special way?
- my node/js understanding is likely thin, I keep hearing querystring is deprecated anyway
- surely there's a usual standard idiomatic way to do this most common of things? "get a html form"
- as I mentioned I don't really ***know*** if this ***is*** a url query string -style string. It's totally undocumented and there's plenty of cases where aws uses something that superficially looks like something else but isn't!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#enctype) (it says there the default enctype for a form is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, further explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)), and that's just how HTML forms work by default, not specific to AWS Lambda. AWS Lambda just gives you the raw body the way the browser sent it.

`querystring` is deprecated in favor of the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) class (which doesn't need an external library as of Node v10):

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(event.body)
console.log(params.get('team'))
```

Comment: WOW 'URLSearchParams' - and no library!  You are a JS God.  TY so much.